# Prototypes and Constructors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var CinemaBooking = function(movieName, customerName) {
  this.customerName = customerName;
  this.movieName = movieName;
};

CinemaBooking.prototype.getCustomerName = function() {
  return this.customerName;
}

CinemaBooking.getMovieName = function() {
  return this.movieName;
}

var c1 = new CinemaBooking("BatMan", "Peter");

console.log(c1.getCustomerName()) // this is working fine
console.log(c1.getMovieName()) // function getMovieName is not defined
```

My doubt here: why `getMovieName` is not becoming a method to `c1` but `getCustomerName` is becoming a method to `c1`?

P.S.: I am new to javascript and trying to understand stuff from Beginning JavaScript and Eloquent JavaScript.

Comment: ES6 has the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) keyword which makes this process way easier.

Comment: With `CinemaBooking.getMovieName` you are not putting this on the prototype —  it needs to be `CinemaBooking.protoype.getMovieName` to link it to prototype inheritance.

Comment: CinemaBooking is variable storing function. You need to put it on "this" object inside function or on prototype object of the function. We should use function declaration to use this inside function, not function expression.

Comment: `getMovieName` is a static function. It can only be acessed as `CinemaBooking.getMovieName()`. This will return `undefined` because there is no static property called `movieName` in `CinemaBooking`

Comment: I know ES6 has class feature, But I need to understand prototype inheritance that's why!

Comment: so we can only add properties to constructors but not methods directly as I did ?

Comment: you can refer https://javascript.info/function-prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in Javascript, functions are objects too, so they are suceptible of having their own methods. Meanwhile, prototype inheritance look at the chain of `prototype` objects to know what method should pass to the created object.

So, doing:

```
CinemaBooking.getMovieName=function(){
    return this.movieName;
}
```

Makes the function object `CinemaBooking` having a new method on its own. But, doing:

```
CinemaBooking.prototype.getCustomerName=function(){
    return this.customerName;
}
```

Prepares things for prototype inheritance when the CinemaBooking function is used as constructor (with the `new`) keyword. So when you create a new `CinemaBooking` object with the `new` keyword, the created object will count with the method attached to its constructor function.

**For more info, check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).**

Comment: so we can only add properties to constructors but not methods directly as I did ? @amedina

Comment: @ShivamKasat If you add a method directly, it's like having a `static` method in other languages. No, you can add a method directly to a constructor function and expect it to be inherited. You need to use the `prototype` object of the constructor function for that.

Comment: @ShivamKasat If this answer has been useful to you, consider marking it as chosen :).